# How to select the last block element in a repeated html in webdriver

Tags: python, css, selenium, webdriver

This is the `html` code. I want to select export `csv` of the last block. which is present in a drop down triangle mark whose `xpath` is

`".//*[@id='table-view-views']/div/div[1]/ul/li[12]/a/span"`

Highlighted mark having same `<div>` and `<ul>` tags but different `<li>` tag. so I want to select last block element through csspath.

[image]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @panchanan You have *never* accepted any answer for your questions. Please strongly consider doing it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use last function xpath which will select last matching node or element.

```
 (//li[@id='ui-menu-item-exportcsv])[last()]
```

Thank You,
Murali

Comment: can you please provide css path to find the last block the div part

Comment: while doing action chain in python selenium webdriver like     actions = ActionChains(driver)                                                                                     actions.move_to_element(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[text()="+sys.argv[4]+"]")).double_click(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[text()="+sys.argv[4]+"]"))                                                                        .perform()  . getting this error    Message: Component returned failure code: 0x8000ffff (NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED) [nsIDOMWindowUtils.sendMouseEventToWindow]

Answer (score 1):

You can select last block using this CSS selector:

```
#ui-menu-widget:not(.breadcrumb-menu):not(.xref-menu)
```

Please note that there is no CSS selector that allows to select parent element, so you cannot use `<li>` elements to select `<div>` with CSS.

Comment: I have tried the code , but it is not working. it is not highlighting the last block/div

Comment: Oh my bad, I had unnecessary `]` after menu. Give updated version a try.